# Opening the Youtube Application from a Webview

Tags: java, android, webview

Here's what I would like to do:

- I have an existing webview with a link to "www.youtube.com/existingchannel"
- I know how to override (shouldOverrideUrlLoading) and detect when that link is clicked
- I would like for the webview to open up the Youtube application to that specific Youtube channel

Does anyone know how to do this??

Again, I am not wanting to open a specific video, but want the Youtube app to open to a specific youtube channel.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is to send an `Intent` with a VIEW-Action:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/existingchannel"));
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE); // Optional, remove if it doesn't work
 startActivity(intent);
```

Thats basically what `WebView` already does, when no `WebViewClient` is specified. Whether the YouTube app actually responds to it is entirely up to the app.